# JQuery plugin for animated click

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do an animated click JQuery plugin from http://ajarunthomas.com/jquery/animateClick/demo/  I used the source code on the demo tab and put it in my html file like this

```
<body>

    <button id="btn2">HELLO!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animateClick.js"></script>    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {

       $("#btn2").animateClick();
    });
    </script>
 </body>
```

Then I took the .js file from the download tab and put it into the folder with my html file but it does not work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

My goal is just to get some kind of jQuery plugin to work in my html file but none of them have worked, and I'm currently trying to do this one.

Edit: also if I change the code inside the function to $("btn2").hide(); then the program works just fine.

Comment: you have an unclosed `<script>` tag and are also including two versions of jquery

Comment: Use only one jQuery reference and remove the unwanted `<script>` tags

Answer (score 0):

Try to call jQuery like this:

---

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

---

Open the browser console and check for errors, then report the results here.

Comment: <body>

    <button id="btn2">HELLO!</button>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" 

integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" 

crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animateClick.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
       
       $("#btn2").animateClick();
    });
    </script>

</body>

Comment: This still just shows the button, but does nothing when the button is clicked. Also I have tried testing it to make sure the document.ready works. and if i change the code inside the function to $("btn2").hide(); then it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome, you have acces to the developper tools (F12). It seems difficult at the beginning but it's very useful.

You have a network tab where you can see the scripts used by your page.
When I have a css or js problem, I usually take a look at the dev tools to see if my js file is accepted.

If not, it's generally a path problem or a syntax error.

Tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

I use a lot Chrome, but if you use another navigator like Mozilla, you also have dev tools (F12).

Answer (score 0):

Try open the browser console (developer tools like Knriano says), if you use Firefox, press Ctrl+Shift+K to access it.

Answer (score 0):

can you confirm that you are having the file by the name ' jquery-1.12.0.min.js ' in your js folder. Because the above code works for me. Note : Only the plugin js file is present in the website. If you don't have the other file, then include

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```